# What is the best book marketing strategy for an audiobook?

Tags: publishing, marketing, audiobook

I'm narrator of a new audiobook. What is the best book marketing strategy for an audiobook? I wrote a book marketing article published by an ezine articles, but I wonder if this type of book marketing is really successful.

Comment: You're asking as the narrator; what is the author's involvement?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience. Here are some possibilities from [this website](https://katetilton.com/25-ways-market-audiobook-quick-guide/). I hope someone with more experience will answer your question.

> Request reviews from audiobook reviewers.
>
> Promote with sites that focus on audiobooks like:
>
> List your audiobook on:Your Website
>
> Share free copies with influences.
>
> Connect with audiobook groups. Here are a few groups to get you
>   started:

Comment: I think this groks with my high level understanding of marketing. Get people talking about it is the goal; anything that "hacks" social networks is the winning strategy once a good-enough product is in hand. So find gatekeepers to the target audience and win them over. -- that said op would do better to reach out to marketers than writers. There's some overlap, but not enough to get a good answer on this site.